# Boot MBR on Mac mini

Tags: linux, uefi, mbr, qubes

I am trying to install Qubes OS Linux on my Mac mini. However I want to install it in a MBR configuration on a separate internal HDD.

Is there a way to configure a mac to boot a MBR disk instead of UEFI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean "GPT" instead of UEFI.  UEFI is a type of firmware interface capable of running a bootloader, GPT/MBR are disk partition table types.

Now to actually answer your question: Yes, you sure can.  However, editing UEFI boot entries is a bit fiddly on a Mac, as I don't believe it follows UEFI standards.  As such, I would recommend using [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to generate the boot entries for you.